# How can git possibly know a SHA-1 before cleaning?

Tags: git

How can `git` possibly know the SHA-1 of a commit **before** applying the `clean` filter?

The filter below just prints `Hello!` to `stderr`:

```
$ cat filter.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hello!" >&2
cat
```

Create a new Git repository, configure `myfilter`, stage `foo` and commit the change:

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/git/.git/
$
$ echo -e '[filter "myfilter"]\n\tclean = "./filter.sh"\n\tsmudge = "./filter.sh"' >>.git/config
$
$ cat .gitattributes
foo filter=myfilter
$
$ echo 1234 >foo
$
$ git add foo
Hello!
$
$ git commit -m "First commit"
[master (root-commit) 637d6c1] First commit
Hello!
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
  create mode 100644 foo
```

The commit's SHA-1 is said to be `637d6c1...` before running the `clean` filter. However, the `clean` filter might change the content of `foo` before committing, right? So `git` couldn't know the SHA-1 beforehand. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're being fooled by output buffering.

Add a `sleep 10` before or after the `echo` in your filter. You'll see the commit isn't displayed by git before the 10s pause.

Comment: The SHA-1 is displayed immediately after entering the command, but `Hello!` takes 10 seconds to be printed.

Comment: That's not what I am seeing here.